# json to php Invalid argument supplied for foreach

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I have a Json file with data displayed below. im trying to insert into another file php code below to db. i keep getting  ERROR: Invalid argument supplied for foreach
and i do not understand why

```
[{
  "DATE": "02-07-2017",
  "TIME": "08:20:48 AM",
  "ACCOUNT ID": "1000",
  "POSITION": "",
  "FIRST NAME": "",
  "LAST NAME": "",
  "ACCOUNT STATUS": "Active",``
  "REAL URL": ""
},{
  "DATE": "02-07-2017",
  "TIME": "08:20:49 AM",
  "ACCOUNT ID": "1000",
  "POSITION": "",
  "FIRST NAME": "",
  "LAST NAME": "",
  "ACCOUNT STATUS": "Active",
  "REAL URL": ""
},{
  "DATE": "02-07-2017",
  "TIME": "08:20:49 AM",
  "ACCOUNT ID": "1000",
  "POSITION": "Ceo",
  "FIRST NAME": "",
  "LAST NAME": "",
  "ACCOUNT STATUS": "Active",
  "REAL URL": ""
}]

$JSON_DATA = file_get_contents('Track.js');
$CLEAN_DATA = json_decode($JSON_DATA, true);
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `Track Employee` VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
foreach (($CLEAN_DATA) as $row) {
  $stmt->bindParam(1, $row['DATE']);
  $stmt->bindParam(2, $row['TIME']);
  $stmt->bindParam(3, $row['ACCOUNT ID']);
  $stmt->bindParam(4, $row['POSITION']);
  $stmt->bindParam(5, $row['FIRST NAME']);
  $stmt->bindParam(6, $row['LAST NAME']);
  $stmt->bindParam(7, $row['ACCOUNT STATUS']);
  $stmt->bindParam(8, $row['REAL URL']);
}
```

Comment: json file with .js extension ? why ?? also validate it from here https://jsonlint.com/ , remove **``** chanracter and add starting [ and ending ] bracket

Comment: This isn't valid JSON - it needs to be wrapped in `[` and `]`.

Comment: Your `json` data is invalid

Comment: i did have it wrapped when posting this comment it kept giving me an error so i had to take it out to get it to post

Comment: json data is not valid for more details: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems with this JSON:

1. JSON array should be wrapped with [].
2. You have unnecessary backticks on the 8th line.

   "ACCOUNT STATUS": "Active",``

When `json_decode` function gets an invalid JSON string, It returns FALSE, and since it is not an array - You're getting the foreach warning.